# Strange sound issue. Hear sound from a running Vbox VM but can't from Xbuntu

Tags: sound, virtualbox, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a weird issue that I have no idea where to even start looking. My sound on my Xubuntu 16.04 is not working if played though the GUI but if I have a VM running in Virtual box I have sound coming from that. Basically I run a radio broadcasting software on a Windows 10 VM and I can hear that coming through my speakers but if I launch VLC on the hose (Xubuntu) and try to play a song. I get no sound. I don't seem to have the speaker icon in my tray like I used to .. and if I open  Pulseaudio Volume Control I can see that VLC is showing output of sound and nothing is muted

I did a complete restart of the server and still the same problem. Like I say.. I'm at a loss now as to even where to start. I'm running the stock onboard audio on an Asus M4A785TD-V EVO (VT1708S 8-Channel High Definition Audio CODEC). Not even sure what type of info would be needed to help diagnose this issue so if you need something added let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that somehow my output was changed from the internal sound card to the HDMI output. I had to go into pulseaudio and change the output which solved my problems.